# Is $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}$ increasing or decreasing?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

> Is $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}$ increasing or decreasing?

$$f(x)= \frac{1}{x}- (e^{x}-1)^{-1}$$

$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^{2}}+(e^{x}-1)^{-2} \cdot e^{x}$$

$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{e^{x}}{(e^{x}-1)^{2}}$$

For all $x \geq 1$ we have that $f'(x) < 0$ $\Rightarrow$ monotonic decreasing function

---

Is this correct?

Comment: Hehe what exactly? Did I differentiate wrong? :o

Comment: Oh now I can see it!

Comment: What do you say now? :-)

Comment: Anyone can tell me please? It's really important for me!

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the last line is less than zero. (Ah, okay, I see it, but it's not obvious; some argument should be made.)

Comment: How would you make it clear? By calculating the limits maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Bringing $f'(x)$ over a common denominator, we find that $$f'(x)=\frac{x^2e^x-(e^x-1)^2}{x^2(e^x-1)^2}$$

Since the denominator is positive (apart from the removable singularity at $x=0$), we focus on proving that $x^2e^x-(e^x-1)^2<0$.  This rearranges to $$x^2e^x<(e^x-1)^2$$ or $$x^2<\frac{(e^x-1)^2}{e^x}=(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})^2$$
Since both $x^2$ and $(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})^2$ are even, it suffices to prove for positive $x$ only that $$x<e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}.$$
The easiest way to do this is with Taylor series, but if you'd like to use derivatives, then we see that $x'=1$ and $(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})'=(e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2})/2=\cosh \frac{x}{2}>1$ for positive $x$.  Since the two sides agree at $0$, the inequality is proved.

Comment: Wow I didn't expect it's going to be that complicated... ^.^

Comment: Neither did I when I first looked at the problem.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

$x>0$: $f'(x)<0$ is the same as $\frac{\sinh(x/2)}{(x/2)}>1$ which means $\frac{\sinh x}{x}>1$ .

This is indeed true, e.g. $\frac{\sinh x}{x}=1+\frac{x^2}{6}+...>1$.